# How does one convert from char format to double format, when working with binary numbers?

Tags: matlab, binary, char, format, double

I have a piece of code which outputs what I want but in the wrong format

```
for k=1:100
    bin(k,:)=dec2bin(randi([0 31]),5);
end
```

I want the output to be a 100x5 double array, with one bit per cell (0 or 1 value).

I've tried using the `double()` function...

```
for k=1:100
    bin(k,:)=double(dec2bin(randi([0 31]),5));
end
```

...but that returns the correct format, with the wrong values.

My jargon might be a bit off, I apologise (Am I using cell, double, etc in the wrong context?)

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do what you want. The simplest would actually be generating the binary array right from the start, without a loop:

```
bin = rand(100, 5) > 0.5
```

Other alternatives:

1. If you have an integer array and you want to convert it to bits, you can use [`bitget`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) instead of `dec2bin` inside the loop:

   ```
   bin(k, :) = bitget(randi([0 31]), 5:-1:1)
   ```
2. If you already have a string array representing binary numbers, and you want to operate on it, you can delimit the bits with spaces and then apply [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html):

   ```
   bin = reshape(str2num(sprintf('%c ', bin)), size(bin))
   ```

Comment: I followed your advice earlier before you edited and that was a good solution. Since your edit, even better! I'm going to follow your advice about generating the binary array from the start.

Comment: For a complete answer, I would add how to convert the logical array output you get using 'bin = rand(100, 5) > 0.5' to a double array. I have found you can include 'bin = +bin' which has the effect of removing the logical flag of the array.

Comment: True, but usually logical arrays are implicitly converted to double anyway in arithmetic operations. Besides, why would you store bits as doubles? It seems like waste of memory.

Comment: I tried to manipulate the array afterwards and had difficulties. I thought that it was due to the logical format. It must have been some other error though, because it is working now! So yes, if it can function in the same way as its corresponding double format, then your answer is 100% complete and correct :)